# Manifest v3 Newtab and background service worker : Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I have my own newtab page which on load access background service worker(making some API calls)

```
"chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "newtab/newtab.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
```

BUT if it is a first tab loaded on the INITIAL browser launch.
It gives this error
**Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist**

Could it be because newtab script is started earlier than service worker listener?

```
runtime.onMessage.addListener
```

Because second newtab is not giving this error. How to fix this?

Comment: You can resend the message using setTimeout until it succeeds.

Comment: You can also make the requests directly without using the background script.